# Issue using DisplayTag library

Tags: displaytag

I am trying to use DisplayTag.jar to display datatable in struts2 based application.I have displayTag-1.2.jar and commons-beanutils-1.8 on my build path ,but still at runtime i get following exception and blank page is displayed :

```
23-nov-2014 0:42:58 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TemplateTag.evaluateExpression(TemplateTag.java:84)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.initParameters(TableTag.java:932)
    at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doStartTag(TableTag.java:767)
    at org.apache.jsp.transactionsData_jsp._jspService(transactionsData_jsp.java:121)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:139)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(St
```

Anybody knows what is the problem ?

Comment: solved.Added commons-beanutils-1.7.

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding commons-beanutils-1.7.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassNotFoundException occurs when java doesnt find class files in its classpath.
class files resides in jars, for this case org.apache.commons.beanutils.NestedNullException class is not found by the JVM,
Please download the jar from below link and add it to your build path.
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
thanks.
```